# Stripe: Is there an element that creates a customer without a charge?

Tags: stripe-payments

Does Stripe have an element that would capture a customers card details but not process any payment?

In my case, I have a form that a client fills out but payment is not processed at that time as the final charges will always change based on what the client needs are. Payment would be processed at a later date.

I did see that WordPress / gravity forms have a module that does this but I would rather not have to create a WordPress site.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Stripe.js with Elements (https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) or Stripe Checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) to collect your customer's card details securely.

Both Stripe.js and Checkout allow you to tokenize a user's credit card details. You can then use those that token/source on your backend to create a new Customer with that token [0] or update an existing Customer.

The Stripe recipe's page actually has an example of using Stripe Checkout to update a user's card details (https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/updating-customer-cards#using-the-token-to-update-the-customers-card).

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=node#create_customer-source

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE**: adding that the new version of Stripe Checkout is a hosted page that allows collecting card details for future use via its **Setup Mode**: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/setup#retrieve-setupintent